# I am having a problem with Reverse method on comment section for a blog post

Tags: django, redirect, comments

I am having a problem with Reverse method on comment section for a blog post. Posting part works fine but its the redirect view which is not working. It greets me with the message:

**Not Found: /article/17/
[18/Jan/2021 03:38:33] "POST /article/17/ HTTP/1.1" 404 1747**

May be it has something to do with the id or i am redirecting in a wrong way ..

Here's what i've done:

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib import messages

from django.urls import reverse
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

from .models import Article
from comments.models import ArticleComment
from comments.forms import ArticleCommentForm

from django.views.generic import (
    ListView,
    DetailView
)



class ArticleListView(ListView):
    model = Article
    template_name = 'articles/home.html'
    context_object_name = 'articles'
    ordering = ['-date_published']
    paginate_by = 5


class ArticleDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Article
    form_class = ArticleCommentForm
    template_name = 'articles/article_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        comments = ArticleComment.objects.filter(
            article =self.get_object()
        ).order_by('created_on')

        data['comments'] = comments
        if self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            data['comment_form'] = ArticleCommentForm(instance=self.request.user)

        return data

    def post(self, request, pk, **kwargs):
        article = get_object_or_404(Article, id=request.POST.get('object_id'))
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ArticleCommentForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid:
                new_comment = form.save(commit=False)
                new_comment = ArticleComment(comment= request.POST.get('comment'),
                                        user = self.request.user,
                                        article = self.get_object())
                new_comment.save()
                messages.success(request, f'Your comment has been posted')
                return reverse(request, 'article-detail', kwargs={id: self.id})
                
        else:
            context = {
                'form': form
            }

        return render(request, 'articles/article_detail.html', context)
```

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import settings
from django.utils import timezone
from articles.models import Article



class ArticleComment(models.Model):
    article          = models.ForeignKey(Article, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='Comments')
    user             = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    comment          = models.TextField()
    created_on       = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    updated_on       = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

   

    def __str__(self):
        return  self.article.title[:50] + ' | ' + 'comments by {}' .format(self.user.username)
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from .models import ArticleComment

class ArticleCommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    comment = forms.CharField(label ='', widget = forms.Textarea(
        attrs = {
            'class': 'form-control',
            'placeholder': 'Conversations',
            'rows': 4,
            'column': 50
        }))
    class Meta:
        model  = ArticleComment
        fields = ['comment']
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views as article_view
from .views import (
    ArticleListView,
    ArticleDetailView
)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ArticleListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    path('article/<int:pk>/', ArticleDetailView.as_view(), name='article-detail'),
    path('about/', article_view.about, name='about'),
]
```

Comment: the easiest way is to add get_absolute_url in models.py

Comment: i do have get_absolute_url in my models.py how do i implement it in the function

Comment: Also Note:..>    i have different apps for article and comments, for comments models and forms i am using Comment App and for views and urls imm using Article App. The code was kindoff long so i decided not to post everything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using

```
return reverse(request, 'article-detail', kwargs={id: self.id})
```

Try using

```
from django.shortcuts import redirect

....
return redirect('article-detail', id=article.id)
```

This should work fine. If it doesn't work, post your `urls.py` in the question.

Comment: I still show me same error. I have update my question with urls.py

Comment: Modified the answer.